# Alamofire: Parameters not being passed to server

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

This is my first time trying to use Alamofire so please forgive me if this is a glaring oversight! I've read a lot of the other answers and have made a lot of tweaks, but nothing seems to work.

I am trying to do a really simple test where a parameter is passed from an iOS app to the server, which checks if it is equal to "Test" and if so, returns some json data back to the iOS app.

Although the debugPrint method outputs SUCCESS, the json data printed by the iOS app is always "Not set", implying that the parameters haven't actually been passed to the php file. I was wondering if someone could help me out!

At the moment I'm not too concerned about parsing the json, but am just trying to figure out the cause of the lost parameter! Thanks in advance.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php  
    $name = $_POST["name"];

    if (isset($name))
      {
        if($name == "Test"){
          echo json_encode("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
         echo json_encode("Incorrect");
        }
    }else{
        echo json_encode("Not set");
    }
?>
```

And here is my swift code:

```
let url = "http://mywebsite.com/xxx.php"

let parameters: [String:String] = ["name":"Test"]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in

    debugPrint(response)

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)") 
    }
    else {
        print(response.result.error!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `URLEncoding.default` to `JSONEncoding.default`.

Setting encoding to `URLEncoding.default` will pass params via query string.
(i.e. http://mywebsite.com/xxx.php?name=test).

Also change `$POST_` with `$_POST`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've tried this but I still get "Not set" and when I try returning $name in json_encode it shows as <null>

Comment: Thanks again, I've changed that but it still returns <null>

Comment: Where're you seeing <null>? In xcode's console? Or while debugging php code?

Comment: Just to debug I tried changing echo json_encode("Not set"); to echo json_encode($name); , and when that data is read by the app the output is JSON: <null>. This is in the xcode console

Comment: Well I'm not so good in php, but try to do `json_encode ` with a valid json, f.e. 
`echo json_encode(array('success' => 'true')`

Comment: The above code with valid json works perfectly, so we know the problem is something to do with the parameters not being posted to the server in the first place